# How to get layout xml file path?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to display the path of layout used in `setContentView(R.layout.main);`. So if the mobile phone is `normal-mdpi`, I need to display "Path is: /res/layout-normal-mdpi" or if the mobile phone is `normal-hdpi`, I need a text "Path is: /res/layout-normal-hdpi".

I basically need to know which layout file was loaded and its path.

Comment: what would you need that for?

Comment: Need to make a specific task. I can do it via TextView with hardcoded path in each resource XML, but that way is way to slow. I need to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a Hidden Text View with corresponding Folder names in the xml 
Get the String in the text view by

```
TextView path = (TextView)findViewbyid(R.id.hiddentextview); 
 String s =  path.gettext().tostring();
```

Make sure that all the id's of the text view are same
Example

> ```
> if your xml is in `normal-mdpi` in hidden textview hard code `normal-mdpi`
> if your xml is in `large-mdpi` in hidden textview hard code `large-mdpi`
> ```

Comment: what is `path`? If I use static class `Path`, I can do nothing.

Comment: Yes, this is the trick I am using right now. It hard as you have to manually hardcode the text into each TextFile. It seems that this is the only solution so far

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Activity.getResources().getConfiguration()` which will get you current [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) - see the doc, you can get most of the info you need from there (namely, you'll want [orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation) and [screenLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#screenLayout)), for screen density you'll want `Activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` and the [density](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density) field. There's no way to retrieve actual layout path that I know of.

**UPD**
Hmm, take a look at this: [LayoutInflater.inflate()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#316) - this is how it's working internally, if you dig deeper - it calls through to a native method that does the actual inflation, so no luck there, but maybe if you poke around with the xml parser, you'll find a way to do that. From the top of my head, you can add a comment to every layout and put the file's name into it. And then use Activity.getResources().getLayout(your_layout_id) to get the xml parser, then use the parser to get your comment out - that way you'll know exactly what file you just accessed.

Comment: So, the only way is the old way - harcoding the name of a resource directory into TextView?! Too bad for this.

Comment: Check out my update in the answer, I got another sort-of-idea on how you can know which layout file you access.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but it seems it's too much work to get nothing, if you know what I mean

Comment: Yeah, I do, that wouldn't be much different from what you were doing so far :)