# Setting different layout for different mobile deveices in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application, I want to set different font size and paddings for different mobile devices. I use this method explain in Android documentation.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

The problem  is that both galaxy s2 and galaxy note 2(720x1280) mobiles use xlarge/my_layout.xml file. These phones have different densities. Therefore, both of them don't behave same way.

For galaxy note 2 xml is perfect but now I need to change paddings of titles and font size for galaxy s2 mobile. Is there particular way to identify 480x800 screen(galaxy s2)?

Answer (score 1):

use folder  **layout-sw360dp** for Nexus 4 and **layout-sw400dp** for galaxy note. may be it will help you.

Comment: currently i am not getting refrence link... but i have found from SO... if you satisfy with answer than accept my answer..

Comment: i have founded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965002/android-resource-selection-layout-and-values-inconsistencies

Comment: this will also affect the layout S3 and GNexus.